# Declaring optional enum values when combining them extending them into a type

Tags: typescript, types, enums

Say that I have two `enums` and either can be the return value for a type:

```
enum Foo = {
  One = "One",
  Two = "Two"
};
```

```
enum Bar = {
  Three = "Three"
};
```

The enums I am actually using have anything upwards of thory values each.

I can say that

```
type FooOrBar = Foo | Bar;
```

As I will not know the resulting type at compilation time for example:

```
type Summary = Record<FooOrBar, unknown>;
```

But at the moment if I have an object that is of type `Summary` it would expect the object to have `One`, `Two` or `Three`.

How could I declare this so that the enum values would be optional and that we would not be guaranteed to get `One` and `Two` if the resulting return type was `Foo`.

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. Is it `type Summary<T extends FooOrBar>  = T extends Foo ? Record<Foo, unknown> : Record<Bar, unknown>` ?

Comment: Are you just asking how to make properties optional instead of required?  You can write `type Summary = Partial<Record<FooOrBar, unknown>>` which is equivalent to `type Summary = {[K in FooOrBar]?: unknown}`.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMxRVN) Or are you looking for something else?  In any case please make sure your code forms a [mre] without typos (no `enum Foo =`) and with sufficient code to demonstrate the use cases that are currently not being met.